# Pre-image of a semi-ring is not a semi-ring. Measure Theory

Tags: measure-theory, semiring

I'm studying measure theory using the book "Introduction to Measure and Integration", from S.J. Taylor.  There, in section **1.5 Classes of subsets**, he defines a Semi-ring as:
"A class $\mathcal{G}$ of subsets that

(i) $ \emptyset \in \mathcal{G} $

(ii) $ A, B \in \mathcal{G}  \Rightarrow A\cap B \in \mathcal{G}$

(iii)$ A, B \in \mathcal{G}  \Rightarrow A \setminus B = \cup_{i=1}^{n}E_{i}$, where the $E_{i}$ are disjoint sets in $\mathcal{G}$.

Now, in the exercises of that section, Exercise 10 (which contains various questions in it) asks to "Give an example of a mapping $f:X\to Y$ and a semi-ring $\mathcal{G}$ in $Y$ such that $f^{-1}(\mathcal{G})$ is not a semi-ring."  Basically, that the pre-image of a semi-ring is not necessarily a semi-ring.  Here $f^{-1}(\mathcal{G})$ denotes the class of subsets of $X$ of the form $f^{-1}(A), A \in \mathcal{G}$.

I am stuck trying to find think an example for this (basically $f$ and $\mathcal{G}$).  Any help/hint is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The comrade below already answered, but I think that the problem is the image if is to found a conter-example. You can take a function non-injective to get $f(A\cap B)\subsetneq f(A)\cap f(B)$ and do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are likely having a difficult time with this exercise because it is not true.

Suppose $\mathcal{G}$ is indeed a semi-ring on $Y$. Recall that $f^{-1}(\mathcal{G}) = \{f^{-1}(U) \mid U \in \mathcal{G}\}$.

Now note that $\emptyset = f^{-1}(\emptyset)$ and that $\emptyset \in \mathcal{G}$. Therefore, $\emptyset \in f^{-1}(\mathcal{G})$.

Suppose $A, B \in f^{-1}(\mathcal{G})$. Write $A = f^{-1}(C)$ and $B = f^{-1}(D)$ for some $C, D \in \mathcal{G}$.

Then $A \cap B = f^{-1}(C \cap D)$ and $C \cap D \in \mathcal{G}$, so $A \cap B \in \mathcal{G}$.

And $A \setminus B = f^{-1}(C \setminus D) = f^{-1}(\bigcup\limits_{i = 1}^n E_i) = \bigcup\limits_{i = 1}^n f^{-1}(E_i)$. Note that each $f^{-1}(E_i)$ is in $f^{-1}(\mathcal{G})$.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I do see that indeed what you wrote makes sense.  I wonder then if I misunderstood the author in his exercise, or is he is not correct in his assertion.